# Showing errors in kamailio syslogs for Register messages

Tags: sip, kamailio

I am getting the below Error messages in syslog. Can anyone tell me why these two methods getting failed. Is there anything I am missing to configure in SIP phone.

*ERROR: {1 2 REGISTER 619499693}  [core/parser/parse_methods.c:456]: parse_methods(): Invalid method*

*ERROR: {1 2 REGISTER 619499693}  [core/parser/parse_allow.c:65]: parse_allow_header(): bad allow body header*

The captured register message below:

REGISTER sip:77.10.86.8;user=phone SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 77.10.86.9:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK1290987256

From: "USER1" sip:90000001@77.10.86.8;user=phone;tag=822848271

To: "USER1" sip:90000001@77.10.86.8;user=phone

Call-ID: 619499693

CSeq: 1 REGISTER

Contact: "USER1" sip:90000001@77.10.86.9:5060

Allow: INVITE, ACK, OPTIONS, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, PRACK, REFER

Max-Forwards: 70

User-Agent: eXosip/3.6.0

Expires: 3600

Supported: eventlist, replaces, tdialog, timer, 100rel

Allow-Events: dialog, message-summary, refer, reg, ua-profile

Content-Length: 0

Answer (score 0):

The from and to headers do not comply with rfc3261 syntax:

```
From: "USER1" sip:90000001@77.10.86.8;user=phone;tag=822848271
To: "USER1" sip:90000001@77.10.86.8;user=phone
```

When a display name is used, the URI needs to be enclosed between <>

```
From: "USER1" <sip:90000001@77.10.86.8;user=phone>;tag=822848271
To: "USER1" <sip:90000001@77.10.86.8;user=phone>
```

You will find more details in rfc3261.

EDIT:

I was too fast in answering. The error mention a wrong value in Allow header. SUBSCRIBER (typo for SUBSCRIBE) is not defined by any specification. However, in rfc3261, such values (unknown) are allowed by the specification, and such header is correct from a syntax perspective.

Comment: Thanks @AymericM. I have also found that in allow header one of the method name was incorrect as it needs to SUBSCRIBE instead here it is having SUBSCRIBER. can i know, is this one caused the above error?

Comment: A wrong method such as SUBSCRIBER in allow header would not be a syntax error! But it may be rejected if they are checked... Seems that was your initial error... Even if not a syntax error...